# Ubuntu 18.04 can not detecting Ethernet

Tags: 18.04, internet, ethernet

I have experiencing some internet issue on my ubuntu 18.04. wifi connection working on Ubuntu but can not detect Ethernet connection.
the out put of **ifconfig -a** shown below:

```
   enx00e04c6860aa: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:e0:4c:68:60:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

   lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 5876  bytes 606809 (606.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5876  bytes 606809 (606.8 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

   wlp59s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.108  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::be69:6edf:643f:b0e0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether f8:e4:e3:01:79:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 46990  bytes 34566067 (34.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 32740  bytes 5759569 (5.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

out put of **cat  /etc/network/interfaces**  below

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

ouput of **sudo nano 01-network-manager-all.yaml** below

```
  # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
    wifis:
      wlp59s0:
    dhcp4: yes
```

How do I get my Ethernet connection working , please HELP need both my Wifi and Ethernet working for my project!!! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Can you update your question to show the output of `sudo lshw -C network`? This will include some hardware-specific information about your ethernet adaptor 